# I made a venv, but why do I still have to use --user?

Tags: python, macos, python-venv

I was under the impression that `--user` was only needed when using system python on the mac.

However, when making a venv and trying to plain pip install things, I was running into errors that were of the system privilege type that usually occur when using system pip without `--user`.

```
pip install tensorflow --user
```

Why does this error occur when on a venv? I would think everything should be installed to the venv's bin? It seems `--user` still fixes it, which I found solved the problem of pip installing it, but something feels wrong.

What is the correct way to dev with python on the mac? I thought venvs were the answer.

```
pip install librosa --upgrade 
 Collecting librosa Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: audioread>=2.0.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (2.1.5) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: decorator>=3.0.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (4.1.2) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: six>=1.3 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (1.11.0) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: scipy>=0.14.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (0.19.1) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: numpy>=1.8.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (1.13.3) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: joblib>=0.7.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (0.11) Requirement not upgraded as not directly
 required: resampy>=0.2.0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from librosa) (0.2.0) Collecting scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0 (from
 librosa)   Downloading
 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/d3/47c2c9842d61042f3c5f082f677dbe05899b077272105906a3249fe8c5da/scikit_learn-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 2.0MB/s Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: numba>=0.32 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from resampy>=0.2.0->librosa) (0.37.0) Requirement not upgraded as
 not directly required: llvmlite>=0.22.0.dev0 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from numba>=0.32->resampy>=0.2.0->librosa) (0.22.0) Requirement not
 upgraded as not directly required: enum34 in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from numba>=0.32->resampy>=0.2.0->librosa) (1.1.6) 
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: funcsigs in /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy>=0.2.0->librosa) (1.0.2) 
 Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: singledispatch in
 /Users/snow_linux/anaconda/envs/fastai_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 (from numba>=0.32->resampy>=0.2.0->librosa) (3.4.0.3) 
 Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, librosa   
 Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.19.0 Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. 

 It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: Did you *activate* the virtualenv? e.g. if you created the virtualenv with `virtualenv ~/myvirtualenv`, did you subsequently do `. ~/myvirtualenv/bin/activate` (or `source ~/myvirtualenv/bin/activate`)? If you don't do that, you're not actually using the virtualenv.

Comment: You're not new to this site. Please take some time and learn how to properly format questions. Command trace should be formatted using code blocks not with quotes. Using block quotes the causes line breaks to mess up. And also, don't put tags in the title.

Comment: Yes, venv was activated. Thanks for feedback. Sorry i posted from my phone and thought the wrapping was an artifact of that